# Does Perl safely defer INT signals during a Storable write?

Tags: perl, io, signals, ipc

I'm concerned about data corruption while executing a `Storable::store` operation. I'm writing about 100 MB to an NFS to backup my calculations at particular checkpoints but the process isn't exactly speedy.

To try to prevent corruption, I have a `SIG{INT}` signal handler. Right before `Storable::store` is called, a global variable is set indicating it isn't safe to terminate. As soon as `Storable::store` completes, that global variable is returned to a value to indicate it's okay to interrupt.

That global variable is used to indicate whether or not the signal handler will call `die` or whether it will just print a statement saying "Can't stop yet."

But am I really helping thing? I see now from reading [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-%28Safe-Signals%29) that interrupting IO is sometimes done safely, and sometimes it is not... That is, should my signal handler end up being called in the middle of my `Storeable::store` operation, such a brief diversion to my signal handler subroutine may still be enough to screw things up.

Does anyone know how `Storable` performs in such a situation? Or is my signal handling setup actually appropriate?

Comment: There are [other things to be concerned about with Storable](http://www.masteringperl.org/?p=15).

Comment: Real quick... brian... big fan! I have "Learning Perl" and "Intermediate Perl". I love both books. They gave me my passion for programming more than anything else. Thank you for such wonderful pedagogical writings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 5.8.1, Perl uses "[safe signals](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-%28Safe-Signals%29)" (by default). When you setup a signal handler through `%SIG`, Perl actually installs a simple signal handler that does nothing but increment a counter. In between Perl ops, Perl checks if the counter is non-zero, and calls your signal handler if it is. That way, your signal handlers don't execute in the middle of a system call or library call.

There are only two things you need to worry about:

- Modifying global vars (e.g. `$!`) in your signal handler.
- System calls returning EINTR or EAGAIN because a signal came in during the call.

Comment: inspection of the code shows that Storable.xs seems to just use PerlIO_write; dunno of that automatically restarts calls (assuming it ends up doing a system call and not being diverted to perl code by an IO layer)

Comment: @ysth, I doubt it. What does Storable do on getting an error from PerlIO_write?

Answer (score 2):

If you're really concerned that `SIGINT` could break `store`, try adding `SA_RESTART` to your signal handler. On Linux, this will force the system calls to be automatically retried upon a signal. This will probably defer your signal handler indefinitely since `SIGINT` will not be able to break out of the I/O operation. However, it should enable safe operation of `Storable::store` under any interruption circumstance.